# how to change the code if the columns are in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
     Sub Button2_Click() 
     'COMPARE colA and colE - if colA=colE, put colG matched to colE
     Dim rngcolE As Range, rngcolA As Range, rngFound As Range, rngSearch As Range

    Set rngcolA = Range("A2:A" & lastRowcolA)
    Set rngcolE = Range("E2:E" & lastRowcolE)

    'searches for all articlesA in column A mentioned in rngcolA:
    For Each rngSearch In rngcolA
     'all articleE are searched in rngcolE:

    Set rngFound = rngcolE.Find(What:=rngSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    'if articleE is found:
     If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
       'found articlesG's cells are entered in column B, against his name given in column A:

    ngSearch.Offset(0, 1) = rngFound.Offset(0, 2)
    End If

    Next

    End Sub
```

to be more specific:
-I have 3 filled columns (colA, colE and colG)
- if an article from colA has a match article in col E, put the matched article from column G in the second column(column B).

MY PROBLEM:
The above code is correct but all columns are in the same Sheet. 
HOW CAN I CHANGE THE CODE IF THE COLUMN-A IS IN THE SHEET1 AND THE COLUMN-E AND COLUMN-G ARE IN  SHEET2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add Sheets("SheetName") before the Range, and replace 'lastRowcolA' with code that will find the last row. So for example:

```
Set rngcolA = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)    
Set rngcolE = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
```

Note that you can't use the Select function for a worksheet other than the one you are currently viewing, but other functions should work fine.

Comment: it doesn't work correctly. I mean, rngSearch.Offset(0, 1) = rngFound.Offset(0, 2) doesn't work.

Comment: If you are trying to set rngSearch.Offset(0, 1) equal to the value contained in rngFound.Offset(0, 2) then you should code this as rngSearch.Offset(0, 1) = rngFound.Offset(0, 2).Value

Comment: Doesn't work because you need to `Set` a range. Since you declared your variables as ranges you can't just `=` them

Comment: So has that solved your query, and the answer can be accepted? Or are you still unsure about something that I can clarify?

Comment: Noldor130884, what should I do instead of "="?

Comment: **user2696883**, I haven't solve my problem yet! Yes, I want to put the value of rngFound's cells in rngSearch. I tried to change the code as you said me but doesn't work. I should see in the B column the rngSearch...but I can't see anything.

Comment: lastRowcolA and lastRowcolE are both invalid strings. I have amended my answer to correct this.

Comment: I put the first part of my code too. _but the problem is with the different sheets_

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I know **user2696883**. I didn't copy entire code. However, here is the first part:

```
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim lastRowcolA As Long
     Dim lastRowcolE As Long
     Set ws = thisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

     With ws
          lastRowcolA= .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
          lastRowcolE = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     End With
```